# "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive." while accessing a web reference

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

I've written a c#/.net program that accesses a Web Reference WSDL made in PHP NuSoap, that accesses a soap method through this call:

```
public kiosk_wsdl.MEMBER_DATA_RECORD record;
using (kiosk_wsdl.kiosk webService = new kiosk_wsdl.kiosk())
{
    kiosk_wsdl.USER user = new kiosk_wsdl.KIOSK_WSDL_USER();
    record = webService.GetMemberDetails("000000000001", user);
}
```

It works well in my localhost and our development servers, but when I transferred the NuSoap server to the production server, this exception occurs when I make the call:

```
    The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
```

with the inner exception:

```
    System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

While in this same production server, the method works well when accessed via a PHP NuSoap Client, so I'm guessing the problem is in my .NET client.

I've googled this problem and some say that it is possible that the server might have a default maximum message size configured to be too small, but how can I modify that in our production server? (and why does it work in our development machines where we have the same NuSoap configuration?) I've tried different solutions but to no avail.